# JavaScript Get Selected Item's TextContent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop

I want to make a program that write out the textContent of the item that has clicked. For some reason this program only get the last element's content. Any idea what should I change inside the for loop?

```js
var emailname = document.querySelectorAll(".name");

var gSenderName = document.getElementById('sname');

$('.name').click(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < emailname.length; i++) {
    const sendername = emailname[i].textContent;
    gSenderName.textContent = sendername;

  }

});
```

```css
.name:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">first</div><br>
<div class="name">second</div><br>
<div class="name">third</div>
<br>

<div>Selected:
  <div id="sname"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the loop here at all. You can simply get the currently clicked element's text by using `this` object. I will also suggest you not mix up vanilla JS and jQuery unnecessarily:

```js
var gSenderName = $('#sname');

$('.name').click(function(){
  gSenderName.text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.name:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">first</div><br>
<div class="name">second</div><br>
<div class="name">third</div>
<br>

<div>Selected: 
  <div id="sname"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs and sets the text content of each item one after the other. Because each override the other, you always get the last one.

Just set the text content of the element that was clicked:

```js
var gSenderName = document.getElementById('sname');

$('.name').click(e => {
  gSenderName.textContent = e.target.textContent;
});
```

```css
.name:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">first</div><br>
<div class="name">second</div><br>
<div class="name">third</div>
<br>

<div>Selected:
  <div id="sname"></div>
</div>
```